# Scaling Elastic Beanstalk for Multi-Tenant Application

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I've migrated a large-ish multi-tenant Laravel app to Elastic Beanstalk, with a MySQL RDS back end. As I bring clients online, my free-tier "micro" single A-Z platform is starting to hang, as expected.

I've read about scaling vertically and horizontally, and EC2 and RDS instance types, but I'm still confused about the best way to diagnose and scale as cost-effectively as possible

The biggest problem are reports: queries with several joins against a few million records. I'm fairly confidant about indexing and other structure issues.

Basic RDS monitoring shows CPU peaking at 20%, "Freeable Memory" at 40-50. EC2 shows CPU Utilization around 10%. Nothing obvious. Still, if multiple such queries are being run, they time out, and the whole system bogs down.

Any advice? Are there other monitors I should be using? Should I just try a bigger burstable RDS instance type (I have everything on one t3.micro RDS instance now. ). One of these other "m" class instances? Will Multi A-Z make a big difference in performance?

Thanks for any advice.
Ben

Comment: Setup read-replicas for those queries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RDS instance type at this time? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance enhancing suggestions.